# Adding shaded boxes in a legend to a bar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a bar graph drawn with `TikZ`.  There are two pairs of bars - really small bar graph that are shaded gray or black.  I want a small square for each in the legend. A small square box shaded black should be to the left of "less expensive gift" and a small square box shaded gray should be to the left of "more expensive gift" in the legend.  Both boxes should be flush against the left edge of the legend.  (I want to keep the code in `TikZ`.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%The two bars for the less expensive gift are drawn. They are shaded black.
\path[fill=black] (0.5,2) -- (0.75,2) -- (0.75,0) -- (0.5,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black] (1.75,2.55) -- (2,2.55) -- (2,0) -- (1.75,0) -- cycle;

%The two bars for the more expensive gift are drawn. They are shaded gray.
\path[fill=gray!50] (0.75,2.75) -- (1,2.75) -- (1,0) -- (0.75,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] (2,2.45) -- (2.25,2.45) -- (2.25,0) -- (2,0) -- cycle;


%The y-axis is drawn. Tick marks along the y-axis are drawn.
%\draw (0,0) -- (0,3.5);
\draw (-2pt,1) -- (2pt,1);
\draw (-2pt,1.5) -- (2pt,1.5);
\draw (-2pt,2) -- (2pt,2);
\draw (-2pt,2.5) -- (2pt,2.5);
\draw (-2pt,3) -- (2pt,3);
\draw (-2pt,3.5) -- (2pt,3.5);

%Labels for the tick marks are typeset.
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,0) +(-0.15,0)$){$0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,1) +(-0.15,0)$){$4.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,1.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$5.0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,2) +(-0.15,0)$){$5.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,2.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$6.0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,3) +(-0.15,0)$){$6.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,3.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$7.0$};

%The symbol for a broken y-axis is drawn.
\draw (0,0.25) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125)$);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125)$) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25)$);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25)$) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25) +(150:0.125)$);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,0.25);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25) +(150:0.125)$) -- (0,3.5);

%The x-axis is drawn.
\draw (0,0) -- (2.5,0);

%The labels "giver" and "recipient" are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(0.75,0) +(0,-0.15)$){giver};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.15)$){recipient};

\node[anchor=south, rotate=90, align=center] at (-0.9,1.75){Mean \\ Appreciation};
\node[anchor=north] at (1.25,-0.5){Role};

\node[align=center, font=\bfseries, anchor=south, yshift=3mm] at (current bounding box.north){Givers' Perceived and Recipients' \\ Actual Gift Appreciations};

\node[draw, anchor=west, align=center] at (3,3){less expensive gift \\ more expensive gift};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in



\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is a possible solution using relative placements of nodes and the fit library:

[image]

**Edit**

Some explanations in reference to the comments: `shape=rectangle` basically defines the shape of the node. However, to define its size, there are three options, `minimum width`, `minimum height` and `minimum size`. While `minimum width` and `minimum height` allow to define both quantities independently, `minimum width` assumes that both are equal. Hence, defining `shape=rectangle, minimum width=...` results in a square.

The alignment of the annotations is done with the help of the positioning library. For example, I place `less expensive gift` right to the previously defined node `leg` by saying `right=0.5em of leg`. You could also just say `right= of leg`, but I didn't liked the output, so I fine tuned the distance by adding `0.5em` (half the font size) between `right=` and `of leg`. Here, leg is just the reference to the previously defined node. The same I do for the second annotation.

Additionally I draw the frame around the annotation by making use of the fact, that all four elements are pre-defined node. By saying `\node[draw, fit = (leg) (meg) (legtext) (megtext)] {};` I am just creating a node, which fits the other four nodes in size, gets drawn and has no further content (hence the empty curly braces).

**Code**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections, positioning, fit}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%The two bars for the less expensive gift are drawn. They are shaded black.
\path[fill=black] (0.5,2) -- (0.75,2) -- (0.75,0) -- (0.5,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=black] (1.75,2.55) -- (2,2.55) -- (2,0) -- (1.75,0) -- cycle;

%The two bars for the more expensive gift are drawn. They are shaded gray.
\path[fill=gray!50] (0.75,2.75) -- (1,2.75) -- (1,0) -- (0.75,0) -- cycle;
\path[fill=gray!50] (2,2.45) -- (2.25,2.45) -- (2.25,0) -- (2,0) -- cycle;


%The y-axis is drawn. Tick marks along the y-axis are drawn.
%\draw (0,0) -- (0,3.5);
\draw (-2pt,1) -- (2pt,1);
\draw (-2pt,1.5) -- (2pt,1.5);
\draw (-2pt,2) -- (2pt,2);
\draw (-2pt,2.5) -- (2pt,2.5);
\draw (-2pt,3) -- (2pt,3);
\draw (-2pt,3.5) -- (2pt,3.5);

%Labels for the tick marks are typeset.
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,0) +(-0.15,0)$){$0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,1) +(-0.15,0)$){$4.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,1.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$5.0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,2) +(-0.15,0)$){$5.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,2.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$6.0$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,3) +(-0.15,0)$){$6.5$};
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0] at ($(-2pt,3.5) +(-0.15,0)$){$7.0$};

%The symbol for a broken y-axis is drawn.
\draw (0,0.25) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125)$);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125)$) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25)$);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25)$) -- ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25) +(150:0.125)$);
\draw (0,0) -- (0,0.25);
\draw ($(0,0.25) +(150:0.125) +(30:0.25) +(150:0.125)$) -- (0,3.5);

%The x-axis is drawn.
\draw (0,0) -- (2.5,0);

%The labels "giver" and "recipient" are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(0.75,0) +(0,-0.15)$){giver};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0] at ($(2,0) +(0,-0.15)$){recipient};

\node[anchor=south, rotate=90, align=center] at (-0.9,1.75){Mean \\ Appreciation};
\node[anchor=north] at (1.25,-0.5){Role};

\node[align=center, font=\bfseries, anchor=south, yshift=3mm] at (current bounding box.north){Givers' Perceived and Recipients' \\ Actual Gift Appreciations};

%drawing legend
\node[shape=rectangle, minimum size=1em, fill=black] (leg) at (3.5,3) {};
\node[shape=rectangle, minimum size=1em, fill=gray!50, below= 1em of leg] (meg) {};
\node[anchor=west, right=0.5em of leg] (legtext) {less expensive gift};
\node[anchor=west, right=0.5em of meg] (megtext) {more expensive gift};
\node[draw, fit = (leg) (meg) (legtext) (megtext)] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip0.25in
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The display is exactly what I want.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `fit` package.  I guess the options `shape=rectangle, minimum size=1em, fill=black` is what draws the square and shades it black.  You say that the shape is a rectangle.  It seems to me to be a square.  This is actually what I wanted.  I want to know how you assured that it to be a square.

Comment: How did you get "less expensive gift" to be typeset to the right of the black square?  Is it from `right=0.5em of leg`?

Comment: See my explanations in the edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Now I know - or now I recall - that the specification `shape=rectangle` is an option for a `\node` command recognized by `TikZ`, and the specification `minimum size=1em` substitutes for "`minimum height=1em, minimum width=1em`."

Comment: I will look at your comments on "relative positioning" more carefully later.  I see that they are part of the "positioning" package.